# Examples of functions mapping rotation matrices to rotations

Tags: lie-groups, rotations

I am wondering if anyone has any good examples of non-linear functions that act pointwise on the entries of a rotation matrix and map it back to a rotation matrix. Explicitly, I am looking for, if they exist, functions
$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for $R \in SO(n)$, $[f(r_{ij})]_{i,j} \in SO(n)$.

Comment: $f(x)=-x$  ?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @JCAA nonlinear

Comment: What do you mean by ''function"?

Comment: @JCAA let me try to re-explain I thought it was clear in post. I am looking for a nonlinear real-value function that acts pointwise on the rotation matrix in SO(n) such that after its p.w. application the output matrix is still a rotation.

Comment: Functions are continious? Smooth?

Comment: Also should one function serve all $n$?

Comment: @JCAA continuous would be nice, I would be open to seeing a discontinuous example. I am personally just interested in SO(3) but if there is a nice generalization that would be cool

Comment: @JCAA This was my guess too, there was nothing obvious coming to mind, but there are a lot smarter people here than me so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 1):

There are such functions for $n=2$. Indeed, take  any function $g:[0,\pi/2]\to [0,\pi/2]$ satisfying $g(0)=0, g(\pi/4)=\pi/4$ and $g(\pi/2-x)=\pi/2-g(x)$. To construct such a function take any function $[0,\pi/4]\to [0,\pi/4]$ which maps $0\to 0$ and $\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$ and then extend it on $[\pi/4,\pi/2]$: $g(x)=\pi/2-g(\pi/2-x)$.

Now extend this function $g$ symmetrically to $[-\pi/2,0]$: $g(-x)=-g(x)$.

Now for every $x\in [-1,1]$ represent $x$ as $\sin(y)$, $y\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and define $f(x)$ as $\sin(g(x))$.

Now if you take any matrix of rotation $\begin{pmatrix}\cos x &\sin x\\ -\sin x &\cos x\end{pmatrix}$, its image is $$\begin{pmatrix}f(\cos x) &f(\sin x)\\ f(-\sin x) &f(\cos x)\end{pmatrix}$$ which is
$$\begin{pmatrix}\sin(\pi/2-g(x)) &\sin g(x)\\ \sin g(-x) &\sin(\pi/2-g(x))\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(g(x)) &\sin g(x)\\ -\sin g(x) &\cos g(x))\end{pmatrix}$$
which is again a matrix of rotation.